# remote messages for git push let Appveyor build fail

Tags: git, powershell, azure, appveyor

I try to build and deploy a website using appveyor.
The created site will be pushed to a gitrepo on an Azure web app that will then deploy the files.

The problem however, the azure server gives feedback while pushing which git returns to the stderr.

```
remote: Omitting next output lines...        
remote: Finished successfully.        
remote: Running post deployment command(s)...        
remote: Deployment successful.
```

Using `--quiet` and `--porcelain` did not help.

Setting this in the PowerShell `$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'` suppressed all but one error. And Build still fails. The last error I can't suppress is

```
Command executed with exception: remote: Deployment successful.
```

The site actually deploys and everything is fine, except the build in AppVeyor is marked as failed and I receive an mail.

It is annoying and it is easy to miss actual problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found out how to suppress the output of the remote. :(

But I could configure the server so it will no longer send messages that will get print to error.

On Azure under your deployment folder edit the deployment hook(`d:\home\site\repository\.git\hooks`).

The original script was:

```
#!/bin/sh
read i
echo $i > pushinfo
"$KUDU_EXE" "$KUDU_APPPATH" "$KUDU_MSBUILD" "$KUDU_DEPLOYER"
```

I then redirected the std stream to null. The new script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
read i
echo $i > pushinfo
if ! "$KUDU_EXE" "$KUDU_APPPATH" "$KUDU_MSBUILD" "$KUDU_DEPLOYER" > /dev/null ; then
  echo 'Build on Azure Failed'
fi
```

I guess when en error happens it still sends the error output to the client, but I'm not sure. So I added an check, that just echos to the client that something was wrong. Which then will fail the AppVeyor build.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-q` switch (quiet) to `git push` command to see if that helps.

Comment: using `--quiet` did not help. the complete command is `git push -q --porcelain --force origin master`

Comment: OK, how do you call it on AppVeyor side exactly? Could you drop a link to a build (or appveyor.yml) please?

Answer (score 0):

From original I understand that you are calling `git push` from PowerShell. Please try to do this from CMD, which is not that sensitive to output written to stdErr.